# react return markup from dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have html saved from wysiwyg editor and fetched from database, I need to display the content which I usually do with

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
```

but now I need to use the formatted content inside another component,

so I am hoping if there is a function to return the markup like this 
var formattedContent = getMarkup(content)//expecting this to do what dangerouslySetInnerHTML does

```
<Highlight search="Condominium" >
    {formattedContent}
</Highlight>
```

because this isn't working

```
<Highlight search="Condominium" >
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
</Highlight>
```

Any help is appreciated as I am nearly struggling for with this more than a day.

What I am trying above is

npmjs.com/package/react-highlighter -- it highlight matched words, but I need to highlight not just plain text but html

Answer (score 2):

The [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) value is an object with `__html` as key and your HTML content as value.

```
<Highlight search="Condominium" >
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
</Highlight>
```

**Update:**

The `Highlight` component has already an Attribute `innerHTML`. You don't need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in your case.

From official [Documentation](https://react-highlight.neostack.com/):

```
<Highlight innerHTML={true}>{content}</Highlight>
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlighter -- it highlight matched words, but I need to highlight not just plain text but html

Comment: :| thanks for that, but it displays like html code,
 <p dir="ltr"><strong>Condominiums</strong>&nbsp;- &nbsp;Condominium ownership constitutes absolute </p> --

Comment: ah you were referring to a wrong package, it is react-highlighter not react-highlight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192908/discussion-between-radonirina-maminiaina-and-code-tree).